# Trying to create dictionary and got TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, object, dictionary, iterable

Maybe it is a stupid question, but I am pretty new in Python. I am truing to create the dictionary of uni grams and to count the probability for each single word in dictionary.
Here is my code

```
filename = 'doyle-27.txt'
word_dict= {}

with open (filename, "r") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        words = line.split()

        for  word in words:
             word = word.lower

        if not word in word_dict:
                 word_dict[word] =1
        else:
              word_dict[word]+=1
for word in word_dict:
    prob =0
    prob =  word_dict[word]/sum( word_dict[word])
    print(prob)
```

and what I got here is an error 'int' object is not iterable. Maybe somebody can help me to fix it. Tanx!

Comment: Could you please paste input data and complete traceback please ?

Comment: **FYI:** `for  word in words: word = word.lower` isn't doing what you think it does.

Comment: `sum(word_dict[word])` is likely where you problem is. `word_dict[word]` returns an integer object, but `sum()` expects an iterable. What were _actually_ trying to do here?

Comment: There are a *lot* of bugs in your code. First, `word = word.lower` should be `word = word.lower()`, or else you are assigning the *function* `word.lower` to `word`. However, this loop won't do what you want it to do, which is to lower-case every word in your list. When you assign to `word`, it doesn't affect the items in the list, it merely reassigns the name `word`

Comment: My bad. Sure it is word = word.lower().

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do : For each of the word in my dictionary assign a counter and initialize it to zero. Iterate through the sentences and increment counts for each of the words they contain. Finally, to normalize the counts vector and create probabilities,  simply divide the word countby sum of all countslike so:    Prob of word = count(word)/sum(count of all wordsin dict)